# How to design a cutout background image?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve the following result in my layout:

[image]

My approach would be to create a custom drawable like below, but obviously I can't use negative dimensions:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
<corners android:topLeftRadius="-25dp"/>
```

How can I achieve such an inset shape?

Comment: In case that is impossible to do in shape API, you can use 9patch to achieve that

Comment: you can also create custom view for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that background by using a vector drawable and draw yourself the rule. I used the following code to generate the following result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="6dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="6.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#1e319e"
        android:pathData="M2,0 h20 q0,2 2,2 v4 h-24 v-4 q2,0 2,-2"/>
</vector>
```

[image]

You can ignore the background and the blue line around the rounded corners because they are from the layout preview. However, this background might not fit your needs (maybe you want bigger corners or more oval shape), so here is a breakdown of what all that `pathData` means (I will also add the coordinates of the point where we are after each command to better visualise this - also, keep in mind that the top left corner is (0,0) and bottom right will be (N,N)):

- `M2,0` move the starting point to coordinate 2,0 so we can start to draw from there - location (2,0)
- `h20` draw a straight line of length 20 rightwards - location (22, 0)
- `q0,2 2,2` draw a curve from the current point; this command might be the hardest to understand because it is a little weird, but here are the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataQuadraticBezierCommands) and a short explanation for it. As you see, I used the lower case `q` because I wanted to draw the curve relative to what I already have, not an absolute value (make sure to read the docs about absolute vs relative). The command takes two sets of values, `q xc,yc xd,yd` with the following meaning: `xd,yd` have to be added to the current point (22,0) to obtain the destination point (22 + 2 = 24 and 0 + 2 = 2 -> (24,2) is the destination point of the curve) and `xc,yc` are the values that we have to add to the current point (still 22,0 in this case, not the destination one) to obtain a "control point" (22, 2) that will decide how the curve is drawn (basically, the lines starting from the control point and end in the starting/ending point of the curve, have to intersect the curve only in these points ([Tangents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent)) - current location of the pointer (24, 2)
- `v4` draw a straight line of length 4 downwards - location (24, 6)
- `h-24` draw a straight line of length 24 leftwards (notice here that using minus we change the direction) - location (0, 6)
- `h-4` draw a straight line of length 4 upwards (same trick with the minus as above) - location (0, 2)
- `q2,0 -2,2` is exactly like the other one and we end up where we started in (2,0)